# Auto-fill rows from columns in another sheet?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2007, google-spreadsheets

I'm using Google Doc's Spreadsheet at the moment and I'm attempting to create the same view in another sheet.

First Sheet:

[image]

*(yes I need these merged cells)*

Second Sheet:

[image]

Unfortunately Google Spreadsheet doesn't seem to recognise the pattern:

```
=Days!B1
=Days!D1
=Days!F1
```

Any ideas how I can fix this so I don't have to manually change the formula everytime I want to add a row?

Comment: So, you're working in a Google Spreadsheet, yet you add three Excel tags. Why don't you visit Web Applications? That's the place to ask all Google Apps related questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting this formula in row 2, it will retrieve every second cell value in row 1 of the "Day" sheet.

```
=INDEX(Days!$1:$1,(ROW()*2)-2)
```

Copy down.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this in the second sheet.

### Formula

```
=TRANSPOSE(FILTER(Days!B1:1, Days!B1:1 <> ""))
```

### Explained

The `FILTER` formula shows the range (`Days!B1:1`) by filtering out empty rows. The `TRANSPOSE` formula will re-arrange the appeance from a horizontal to vertical one.

This approach is meant to be used in Google Spreadsheets, taking full advantage of its functions.

### Screenshot

[image]

### Example

I've created an example file for you: **[Auto-fill rows from columns in another sheet?](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/17iVhUx01hBIsp4-tKAS3sD28Vw-KlkxCstkf5r8-4_o/edit?usp=sharing)**